# Number of electron for complete Discharge

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis

What is the answer for question 17 and what is mean by "number of electrons for complete discharge?"

[image]

Which of the following needs the largest number of electrons for complete discharge during an electrolysis process?
a) 3 mol of $\ce{Al^{3+}}$
b) 4 mol of $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ ions
c) 5 mol of $\ce{OH^-}$ ions
d) 7 mol of $\ce{O^{2-}}$ ions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{a)} 3\times+3 = 9$$ 
$$\text{b)} 4\times+3 = 12$$ 
$$\text{c)} 5\times-1= -5$$ 
$$\text{d)} 7\times-2 = -14$$ 
This seems like an ambiguous question.

- b) "needs" the most electrons supplied to become neutral
- d) "gives up" more electrons than b) to become neutral.

I'd have to take "needs" literally and go with b) as the answer.